# GlReadPixels always takes from the depth buffer 0

Tags: c++, qt, zbuffer

The situation is, there are many surfaces that intersect and there is no need for the mouse click to determine the actual coordinates of the cursor position, if it points to what or surface, for this I wanted to use `glReadPixels`, paint all over shaders, and eventually `glReadPixels` gives me the depth of the current pixel is always equal to `0`, because of what this could be, and may have any of the functions of alternatives for newer versions of `opengl`, looking for information on the forum, but found that I could help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, you want to find coordinates of interscetion of some objects. Correct?

You can't do any of these with glReadPixels, because this fuction returns color of pixel. Pixels are flat (as your computer screen is), so there is no depth written.
It just gets info from the result image on the screen.

Here is nice quote:
"OpenGL is not a scene management library. It is just a drawing API that draws things onto the screen and then forgets about them."

So my guess is that you would have to do some tricks in your code and calculate everything with your own functions according to how your code works.

Comment: I am writing in Qt using openGl a 3D widget, which displays a variety of objects. It is necessary to find the coordinates of the point (which of course will be on-site) under the cursor, if it points to the coca-object respectively. All rendering goes through shaders.
I want to get the depth value of the depth buffer in a given pixel, a lot of which shows how to do this, and I do the same, but glReadPixels always tells me that the depth of any pixel is 0.

Comment: QVector3D iGLView::GetRealPos(int x, int y)
{
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projectionmtr[16];
    GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
    GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;
    glReadPixels( x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );
// Here is always written in the variable winZ 0

    gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projectionmtr, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

    return QVector3D(posX, posY, posZ);
}

Comment: you could search for collision detection. that's not done in opengl though

Answer (score 0):

I am writing in Qt using openGl a 3D widget, which displays a variety of objects. It is necessary to find the coordinates of the point (which of course will be on-site) under the cursor, if it points to the coca-object respectively. All rendering goes through shaders.
I want to get the depth value of the depth buffer in a given pixel, a lot of which shows how to do this, and I do the same, but glReadPixels always tells me that the depth of any pixel is 0.

```
enter code here

initializeOpenGLFunctions();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//корректное отображение перспективы
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER,0);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// включение обновление буфера глубины
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// очистка буфера
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projectionmtr[16];
GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

viewport[0] = 0;
viewport[1] = 0;
viewport[2] = geometry().width();
viewport[3] = geometry().height();
QMatrix4x4 mtr =  mCameraMatr * mObjectMatr * mScale * mCentrTr * translate;

int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<4; ++j)
    {
        modelview[k] = mtr(j,i);
        ++k;
    }
}

k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<4; ++j)
    {
        projectionmtr[k] = projection(j,i);
        ++k;
    }

winX = x;
winY = viewport[3] - y;

glReadPixels( x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );// Here is always written in the variable winZ 0

gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projectionmtr, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

return QVector3D(posX, posY, posZ);
```